# How can I transfer ArrayLists between classes?

Tags: java, list, getter-setter

I am a rather large-scale noob. I have come across the answer a multitude of times, but, it was just not in a format I could understand. Right now, I am attempting to send a List full of values, to a separate class. I tried each of the resources but to no avail. Apologies if this is an inappropriate question here, a simple ask-with-no-code.

Comment: What was the answer you found, and what didn't you understand about it?

Comment: Yes, it is inappropriate. The question is way too vague, there's no context, no code, and you didn't explain what you've tried and where you got stuck. Please visit the [help], read [ask] and improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need a method or a constructor on the class the receives the ArrayList that accepts ArrayLists.

Pseudocode:

```
public class Class1 {

    //Constructor
    public Class1(){}

    //Methods
    public ArrayList createArray(){
        //Your code here
    }

}

public class Class2 {

    //Constructor
    public Class2(ArrayList myArray){
        //Your code here    
    }

}


public class Test{
    Class1 c1 = new Class1;
    ArrayList array = c1.createArray();
    Class2 c2 = new Class2(array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class list_receiver{ //class in which you want to send your list 

  public void print_array_list(ArrayList<String> l ){
     System.out.println(l);
    }
 }

 class list_sender{//class from where you are sending your list
    public static void main(String args[]){
   list_receiver r = new list_receiver();
   ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
   list.add("A");
   list.add("B");
   r.print_array_list(list);
   }
}
```